# Laravel unable to select last row. "Call to a member function first() on a non-object" error

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-4

In my database table which is called **Access**, I have these data, where a user can have many entities.

```
PrimaryID|UserID|EntityID
-------------------------
1        | U9   | S4
2        | U9   | S5
```

Example, User9 is handling School no.4 and no.5.

I wanted to get a specific column of the last row.

I tried with these:

```
$eid = DB::table('accesscontrols')->where('UserID', '=', $admID)->pluck('EntityID')->first();
$schname = DB::table('school')->where('SchoolID', '=', $eid)->pluck('SchoolName');
```

But it gave me this error instead:

> Call to a member function first() on a non-object

From what I understand, I queried out: `Select` last row EntityID `from` accesscontrols `where` `('UserID', '=', $admID)`

And shouldn't the function first() should return the last row of the table?

I need some help here! What did I went wrong?

Comment: The error is in the first or in the second line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pluck returns a single column's value from the first result of a query.

```
$eid = DB::table('accesscontrols')
->where('UserID', '=', $admID)
->orderBy('PrimaryID', 'desc')
->pluck('EntityID');

$schname = DB::table('school')
->where('SchoolID', '=', $eid)
->orderBy('PrimaryID', 'desc')
->pluck('SchoolName');
```

Added `orderBy()` by primary id, assuming it is auto incrementing, to get the last result.

If you want a whole last row, instead of a single column of that row, then replace `pluck('column_name')` by `first()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @delmadord ! It works perfectly now!! Appreciate your help! :)